What is the name of comedy movie involving God?
I saw a trailer of the movie in which a guy is a God in a city. He irritates people. He has got a lab or something. There is a little girl around 13 or 14 and a woman in the movie. One of the dialogue he speaks about Jesus with father, in a church is

I am God, he did nothing, except getting himself crucified.

I am sure that it is not an English language movie.

Most probably you're after The Brand New Testament (Le Tout Nouveau Testament), which is a co-production between Belgium, France, and Luxembourg.

God lives in an apartment in Brussels, which he shares with his meek
  wife and his 10-year-old daughter Ea.
God is a grumpy sadist who created humankind specifically to have something to torment. He manipulates reality via a personal computer, which he strictly forbids his family from accessing.

